# Intellij change "first suggested fix" key?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shortcut, keymapping

I can't find the KeyMap entry for changing the default <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the first selected fix (in Java code) for a problem in Intellij.

See this screenshot:

[image]

I think the combination is too difficult (I'd like to use one hand and max two fingers) and want to change it to Eclipse's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

How to change this?

Comment: In what way is it too difficult? A large proportion of IntelliJ shortcuts involve three keys, not sure what makes this any different.

Comment: I want to use less fingers (two max if possible, for actions that I perform often)

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu. And `Alt`+`Shift`+`Enter` shortcut doesn't work. So I'm stuck with mouse clicks where, before, I could use `Alt`+`Enter`. I'm eager for a rollback on this feature or a way to change the shortcut.

Comment: Actually the reason I want to use less fingers is that I want to use my left hand for this combination, while I operate the mouse on the right hand. `Alt+Shift+Enter` with one hand is just too hard ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217465
As a workaround you could put caret on red code, press "Alt+Enter" and select suggestion with arrow keys.